# How can I test that a macro is being used in global/namespace scope?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to write a header that lets me *declare* preferences with a syntax similar to:

```
declpref("some.pref.name", "description");
```

Which registers `some.pref.name` with the given description with some global registry so I can easily introspect what preferences my code has declared, set their values from various sources, etc.

I'd probably do this with some sort of static-construction before main magic:

```
#define declpref(name, desc)                       \
    {                                              \
        static struct __pref {                     \
            __pref() {                             \
                register_preference(name, desc);   \
            }                                      \
        } __static_pref;                           \
    }
```

The problem being that the above code wouldn't work the way I want it to if used in a local scope:

```
void some_function() {
    declpref("some.pref", "description"); // won't register until some_function called
}
```

I think that I'm OK with forcing preference *declarations* to be done at global/namespace scope since they're supposed to be a globally unique name anyways.

How can I check the scope that its being declared in and throw an error though?

Comment: Instead of `static` keyword, use an unnamed namespace. Those won't compile if used anywhere other than the namespace scope.

Comment: I like it, any thoughts on how I could possible generate a more useful error message though?

Comment: put it in a blank `namespace`. IOW put `namespace` before your first opening brace

Comment: Guys if you have answers put them as such

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but another way to do this is to define a static pod object with a preference's data and give it a linker section attribute.  This will cause all objects to be contiguous in one section of the program's image, with knowable start/end address.  IOW, all the objects that were defined automatically become elements of one big array when linked, which you can then process at an appropriate time.  Avoids running constructors before main() and lets you have more static const read-only data.